# Dial PPPoE via VLAN on MacOS (get PPPoE and VLAN work together)

Tags: macos, network

I got VLAN ID and PPPoE credentials from my ISP for connecting to the Internet. It works flawlessly on my main router – I activated VLAN tagging on the WAN port (VLAN ID 100) and created a PPPoE client on this VLAN interface, and the Internet is working.

I'd need to set up the same type of connection also on my Macbook (macOS 13 Ventura or macOS 12 Monterey).

It's useful for me to be prepared to connect directly anytime when my main router is broken or non-working. I'm trying to use the Ethernet adapter, adding VLAN 100 to it, and setting up a PPPoE connection over the created VLAN 100 tag.

It's easy to [add a VLAN](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15134/mac).
[image: adding VLAN 100 dialog]

It's also easy to [add a new plain PPPoE connection](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2714/10.14/mac/10.14).
[image: adding a new plain PPPoE connection]

But the newly created vlan0 interface (VLAN 100) is not showing up in the "Use this interface" dropdown menu of the PPPoE connection settings dialog. I can only select simple untagged interfaces, like an untagged Ethernet port.

[image: add PPPoE dialog does not show VLAN interface in the list]

**How can I set up a PPPoE client on VLAN 100 Ethernet interface on macOS?**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. While you have provided a comprehensive background, where's the question? Please make an edit to clearly state the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the VLAN interface
2. Click Apply
3. Create the PPPoE interface
4. Click Apply
5. Exit Network Preferences
6. Re-open Network Preferences (and now the PPPoE username and password fields show)
7. Enter your PPPoE username and password from your ISP

However, your mileage may vary, as in my case I was not able to successfully connect to my FTTH ISP's PPPoE server this way via the GPON providers ONT.

The error message I received was "Could not find a PPPoE server." and in Console.app the error from `pppd` (2.4.2 / Apple version 884) was `PPPoE connection failed, No route to host`.

Hopefully you have more luck!